# Show text when number is above 1.000

Tags: php, smarty

I am trying to show text on a product page, when the price is above 300. I am using the following code:

```
 {if $product.integerprice >= 300} Free shipping {/if}
```

$product.integerprice is the price.

It works, but only up to 1.000 (which is 1000, but the price is generated with a dot for thousands). After 1.000, it stops showing the text.

I haven't got any luck figuring the problem, hope someone can guide me.

Comment: Is this some kind of template language? The syntax looks strange to me. Anyway, it *could* be that `1.000` is interpreted as 1, because the dot will be parsed as decimal separator instead of thousands separator. What's the value of `$product.integerprice`?

Comment: Oh it's Smarty.

Comment: It's a custom platform, it's outdated, I am working with what I've got :) Yes, I was also considering that 1.000 is interpreted as 1000, but couldn't think of a workaround.

Comment: Do you have control over the `integerprice` variable? Because `integerprice` shouldn't contain a string with thousands separators. It should contain the price as an int, when *displaying* its value, you should format it accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I only have access to the .tpl files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dot is the problem, then just get rid of it:

```
{if str_replace('.', '', $product.integerprice) >= 1000} Free shipping {/if}
```

So why does 300 work then? In your case you are comparing a string to a number. PHP automatically converts your string to a number in that case. So you have:

`'300' >= 300 //true`, string converted to 300

`'1.000' >= 1000 //false`, string converted to 1, since PHP thinks it's a float.

**due to question update** – I'm not strong in smarty. But I guess you can do the same (remove dot) with [replace](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.replace.tpl).

Comment: Lol, I've changed your link to refer to the English version. Reading Russian is pretty hard for most of the readers. ;-)